# Identifying file using metadata across different paths

Tags: c#, windows, file-io

I have a win service writing a file "a.txt" to folder "Input". 
From here, another third party service peruses the file and places it back after modification in folder "Output".
Using the filename "a.txt", I can identify that the file placed in Input has been processed and received bny Output.

My problem is, that updated versions of the same file may be written to "Input" even as I wait for the processed copy to be returned to "Output". 
So in such a case, when I find "a.txt" in "Output", how do I determine which version of the original file it is?
I tried using the FileInfo.CreationTimeUtc property, but that changes for "Output". 
Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to look at the design approach -- isn't there a risk of third-party overwriting output/a.txt before you had a chance to process it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add date and time to file name on output.

1. Read Input file and its CreationTimeUtc
2. Write output file with name a-CreationTimeUtc.txt

### EDIT

As you say you cant change file name, a second option would be writing the date and time in the file itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have that option. The filename follows a specific format.

Comment: Then maybe on the file content itself?

Comment: Yes, that should work, thanks. The only issue I see with that is that with a high number of files to process, each file's content would have to be read to make this decision.

Comment: Yes, but if you can't change the name, you may have not a better option. I've edited the answer, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any control over the third-party service writing a.txt to output?  If so, FileInfo.CreationTimeUtc is both read and write.  After putting the file into output, it could take the creation time from the file processed and set that on the file in Output.

Comment: Nope, no control, that's why I specifically called it 'third-party'. :) Thanks though, that is a good option to be used when one does control both sides.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't control the third-party tool, you need to control the only thing you can -- the file you write.  If a write to "a.txt" instead writes to "a.timestamp.txt" you can see which versions have been processed.

Comment: Thanks, have to maintain the filename format, so can't do that.

Comment: @shashankss, how do you guarantee atomicity and ordering?  That is if you write `Input/a.txt` you'll begin generating `Output/a.txt`.  But if a second write to `Input/a.txt` happens you'll generate `Output/a.txt` again.  Without further information, it seems that the first processing step could read a mix of original file and update, or the second processing step could complete before the first finishes.  This processing pipeline smells racy to me the way it is described.

Answer (score 0):

As you say that you can't change the name of the file you have the following options

- use one subdirectory per file if that is supported by 3rd-party "service"

**OR**

- maintain a "Queue" per filename
  whenever you generate a file you store it with a unique name in a temp folder - not with the "real" name (as per your naming convention)... you maintain a Collection (Dictionary with "real" name => Querue of unique names) and a "WorkItem"-List... you then move a unique name to the "Input" folder with its "real" name and add that name to your "WorkItem"-List... when that file appears in your "Output" folder then you remove it from the "WorkItem"-List and dequeue it from the Queue within the Dictionary... the "move to Input folder" always checks first whether the "real" name is already in the "WorkItem"-List and if so it doesn't move it.

Answer (score 0):

You could monitor the directory and store the file which was placed in Input in a second directory (if you really can't use the same directory) with the modified filename.

1. Third-Party stored file in Input: a.txt
2. Your program recognizes a.txt and copy it into Input/Queue/a.Timestamp.txt
3. Your program will process each file and copy it to output.

If you can't use the Timestamp in the output directory you would have to wait until the file from Output is processed too so you will not override it. The problem I see in generell is if there is no lock or something like that on the file a.txt. a.txt could be written twice and the first version will not be processed at all. Like already stated. Better would be some kind of not filebased queue or more unique names in Input. Even if you haven't direct control over the third-party service this could be a big issue...